# Remove all quotations within a string

Tags: python, string

- I just want to remove all quotation marks from a string.
- I've tried using `.strip()` and a for loop and that doesn't work either.
- What am I doing wrong?
- I know this question is similar to a few others on stack overflow, I looked at them, and they didn't give me a straight answer.

```py
string = """Hi" how "are "you"""
string.replace('"',"")
print(string)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable in python, [`string.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) can't mutate an existing string so you need to do

```py
string = """Hi" how "are "you"""
new_string = string.replace('"',"")
print(new_string)
```

Or reassign the existing variable with the new value

Answer (score 0):

There you go.

```
string = """Hi" how "are "you"""
string = string.replace('"','')
print(string)
```

or (prefer this method to get rid of unwanted characters.)

```
string = """Hi" how "are "you"""
for i in range(0, len(string)):
    string = string.replace('"','')
print(string)
```

Comment: A single `.replace()` call will replace all replacement characters.  Why call it multiple times?  Additionally, you can simplify to `for _ in string`.   But again, it’s not needed.

Comment: the repeated `.replace()` is not *required*. the string gets checked for all quotation marks and replaces with no quotes with only the first line.